# Trying to get Longitude and Latitude to show on the screen

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I need the longitude and latitude to show on the screen I have looked at some examples from corona SDK,
https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/location/latitude.html
I am just still struggling

This is what I have right now and it's just displaying these same co-ordinates everytime that is no where near where I am.

```
local latitude = display.newText( "-", 100, 50, native.systemFont, 16 )

local longitude = display.newText( "-", 100, 100, native.systemFont, 16 )

local locationHandler = function( event )

    if ( event.errorCode ) then
        native.showAlert( "GPS Location Error", event.errorMessage, {"OK"} )
        print( "Location error: " .. tostring( event.errorMessage ) )
    else
        local latitudeText = string.format( '%.4f', event.latitude )
        latitude.text = latitudeText

        local longitudeText = string.format( '%.4f', event.longitude )
        longitude.text = longitudeText
    end
end

-- Activate location listener
Runtime:addEventListener( "location", locationHandler )
```

Comment: What do you mean by _and it's just displaying these same co-ordinates everytime_?

Comment: Try [Corona University - GPS - Sample Code Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KtdE8UCN0A) on Youtube and [location (GPS)](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/location/index.html) in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this code on the simulator? Even the XCode simulator? If so, that's why... The simulators will give you (last time I checked) somewhere in California as a default (I'm not sure it can be changed) because most laptops don't have a GPS unit.

You need to run the code on an actual device to test the location code properly. The easiest way to do that is to use Corona Live, which makes it super easy to change your code and redeploy to a number of devices without any effort.